# Application cache only when users want it?

Tags: html, offline-caching, application-cache

Some browsers does not asks the client if he want use the application cache, but simply just downloads the whole thing at first visist (e.g. the browser on android). That can cause troubles when the application cache is many MB's and the client is on a mobile network - that is expensive! And is it possible to stop the cache from being downloaded? Pressing the menu button on e.g. android will not close the browser, it will be running in the background.

Is it a good idea to only add the manifest based on a cookie set when the client pushes a "hey i want to offline cache this site" button? Will that cause any new challenges?

---

I've tested this, and it seems to work. Needs more testing though. Can provide a link to the site in about two weeks if anyone is interrested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution, as a you hinted at yourself, would be to ask the user if he/she wants to cache the app offline, and if so, only then redirect to a page which has a link to the manifest file (which is subsequently downloaded by the browser). You cannot stop a download midway unless of course, your network disconnects mid way.

Comment: You'll need to set a cookie - when this is set, you add the manifest file to the <html> tag. The manifest needs to de defined on all pages that is using at app cache.